# Searching through all references on code completion in visual studio 2015

Tags: c#, visual-studio, resharper, visual-studio-extensions, code-completion

is there an extension for searching through all references in current project on **code completion** in visual studio 2015 like what *Resharper* do?

**IntelliSense** I mean.

any help would be appreciated.

Comment: what kind of references you want to search? project reference or others? please provide some screens shot. in addition, you could also write a custom extension to achieve it. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee372314.aspx

Comment: I mean project references on code completion, ReSharper do this, it searches through your project and find what you looking for then add its using directive on top of the class you are . can we achieve this without ReSharper?

Answer (score 0):

You can find all assemblies used by your class:

Random class:

```
public class Test
{
    XDocument xDoc { get; set; }
    List<int> myList { get; set; }
    DataTable dataTable { get; set; }
}
```

Getting assemblies:

```
Type t = typeof(Test);
var assemblies = t.Assembly.GetReferencedAssemblies();

foreach (var item in assemblies)
{
        Console.WriteLine(item.Name);
}
```

Is it what you need?

Comment: thanks for your help but this is not what is looking for, in code completion, I mean IntelliSense. 

Answer (score 0):

There isn't built-in support for this as of Visual Studio 2017 RTM. (We're thinking about it though...)